# Able to connect to SQL Server from SQL Server Management Studio, but not from Reporting Services Configuration Manager

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

I get the following message:

> A connection to the computer cannot be established

I have tried registering it, but my credentials that work to get into the server in SSMS do not work when trying to register it. I have the TCP/IP and Shared Memory Protocol Names Enabled in the SQL Server Configuration Manager and have tried stopping and starting the server. I did not make this server, could that be a reason why I cannot register it? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Has SSRS been configured for that machine yet?

Comment: I do not know, how would I go about finding out?

Comment: Are you launching the SSRS Configuration Manager from your local machine and is that when you get this error?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: When you say register do you mean enable? Are you attempting to turn on SSRS via the Configuration Manager or via SQL Server Configuration Management? Is the service running (Services-->ReportServer or ReportServer$MACHINE_NAME?

Comment: If your report server is on a different server (physical or VM) from your database server, then perhaps there are no firewall rulers on port 1433 between the 2 servers?